# How to distinguish list pattern using a regex in python

Tags: python, regex, xml, python-3.x, regular-language

I am trying to convert an XML to JSON without using python package. To do so I am converting the XML to a list which will be eventually converted to a nested dictionary and then to JSON. I am unable to distinguish the following elements while reading the XML from a list :

1. `<Description>TestData</Description>\n`
2. `Data</Description>\n`
3. `<Description>Test\n`

The regex I am using to distinguish 1 and 3 are :

1. `x = re.compile("<Description>(.+?)<\/Description>\n")`
2. `x = re.compile("^((?!Description).)*<\/Description>\\n")`

I am finding it difficult to develop a regex for the THIRD one.

3. `x = re.compile("\s*<Description>(.+)(?!((<\/Description>)))\n")`

Although the second regex identifies the text 3 correctly **it is also identifying the text 1**. This should identify only text 3.

Comment: Do not use regular expressions to parse XML. Your code will be wrong. Use an XML parser. (Incidentally, none of the three fragments you have posted are elements.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close. This regex works for what you need:

```
re.compile("\s*<Description>(.+)(?<!<\/Description>)\n")
```

I just added the '<' between the ? and ! to make a negative lookbehind assertion. Check this for more info: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

```
<Description>([^<]+)\n
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zuUjT4/7)

python script is

```
 ss=""" <Description>TestData</Description>\n
  Data</Description>\n
  <Description>Test\n"""

regx= re.compile("<Description>([^<]+)\n")
capture=regx.findall(ss)
print(capture)
```

output is

```
['Test']
```

It seems `capture[0]` value is what you want..